# Find all consecutive sequences in an ordered set

Tags: c++, complexity

I have the following set. `a = [1,2,3,4,5]` and i want to find all of the following sequences of consecutive elements:

```
1,
1,2
1,2,3
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4,5
2,
2,3,
2,3,4,
2,3,4,5
3,
3,4
3,4,5
4
4,5
5
```

This is the following code that I use and works correctly. My only problem is with the complexity of the algorithm **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**. Is there a better approach that I can use to reduce the complexity?

```
    int main()
    {
        int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
           vector<vector<int>> all;
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
            {
                vector<int> g;
                g.push_back(a[i]);
                all.push_back(g);
               for(int j = i+1; j < 5; j++)
               {
                    g.push_back(a[j]);
                    all.push_back(g);
               }
               g.clear();
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < all.size();i++)
            {
               for(int j = 0; j < all[i].size();j++)
               {
                    cout << all[i][j] << "  ";
               }
               cout << endl;
            }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Do you just want to print them out, or do you want them stored in `all`.

Comment: @Dukeling I just want to store them in **all**. The printing part is just to test if my work was ok that's all. I can remove the printing part from the question, if it doesn't help.

KEEP IN MIND: **all** is a vector of vectors. So every line in the output is a vector!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only for comparison, counters first

```
static const int N( Max * (Max + 1) / 2); // number of all permutations
static int Max(5); // series upper bound
int vc(1); // vector counter
static int seed = 1; // counts upwards after each full series
static int vmax = seed; // starts at floor during every series
```

for each is passing every vector here

```
void v_perm(std::vector<int>& vref) {
    for (int i(0 + seed); i <= vmax; i++) { vref.push_back(i); }
    vmax++; // grows to ceiling
    if (Max < vmax) { seed++; vmax = seed; } // floor gets raised after each series
}
```

and main employs the for_each

```
int main() {
std::vector< std::vector<int> > all(N);
std::for_each(all.begin(), all.end(), v_perm);
}
```

Comment: The `static` counters are kinda nasty, though.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get better than `O(n²)` because the result has the size of `O(n²)`

The Output has `(n+1)*n/2` elements therefore you will always need `O(n²)` time to do the output.

You can only try to reduce the constant factor.

Answer (score 2):

As @MrSmith42 points out, the complexity can't be improved.

However, at the least, it would be a good habit to separate the routines for

- initialization of your input
- calculation
- output

Here's how it could be better expressed in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const vector<T> &v) {
    out << '[';
    for (typename vector<T>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) {
        if (i != v.begin()) {
            out << ", ";
        }
        out << *i;
    }
    out << ']';
    return out;
}

template<typename T>
vector<vector<T> > consecutive_sequences(const vector<T> &v) {
    vector<vector<T> > all;
    for (typename vector<T>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) {
        for (typename vector<T>::const_iterator j = i; j != v.end(); ++j) {
            all.push_back(vector<T>(i, j + 1));
        }
    }
    return all;
}

int main() {
    const int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    const vector<int> a_vec(a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]));
    /* An alternative to the above in C++11…
     #include <numeric>
     vector<int> a_vec(5);
     std::iota(a_vec.begin(), a_vec.end(), 1);
    */

    std::cout << consecutive_sequences(a_vec) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3], [3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4], [4, 5], [5]]